# Shell script help! Looping over directories under a directory

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script that loops through all directories under a directory, and call a java program with the directory name as an argument at each iteration.

So my parent directory is provided as an argument to the shell script: eg:

```
. myShell.sh  /myFolder/myDirectory
```

There are 100 directories under `/myFolder/myDirectory`. For each "directory_i", i want to run:

```
java myProg directory_i
```

If someone can provide me with a working shell script that'll be perfect!

Comment: Are there sub-directories to the directories in /myFolder/myDirectory?  If so, a 'find'-based solution will go deep, which may not be what you want.  If not, then find works fine.

Comment: Also, using '`. myShell.sh /myFolder/myDirectory`' is unorthodox (not wrong, just probably not what you intended). It makes the current shell read and execute the contents of myShell.sh - and any variables set by the script, for example, are set in your shell; any functions are now in your shell, etc. Usually, you'd use "`sh myShell.sh ...`" or just "`myShell.sh ...`"

Comment: ...or `./myShell.sh ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

The myShell.sh script might look a bit like this, this is a version that will recursively process any and **all subdirectories** under your target.

```
DIR="$1"
find "$DIR" -type d -exec java myProg {} \;
```

The exact set of `find` options available depends on your variety of unix.  If you don't want recursion, you may be able to use `-maxdepth` as Neeraj noted, or perhaps `-prune`, which starts get a bit ugly:

```
find "$DIR" \( ! -name . -prune \) -type d  -exec java myProg {} \;
```

**EDIT**: *Added prune example.*

Comment: anyway this answer is complete.

Comment: @Saobi - it works for me.  I don't have your java program to test with though.

Comment: @Saobi - your comment was rude, when people spend time helping you at least make the effort to try out what they suggest

Comment: "plz email me teh codez!" ... too bad we can't downvote comments

Comment: @martinclayton (or anyone else) how could I modify this to execute multiple shell scripts on every directory?  Or should I make a question for that?

Comment: @KristenHammack - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands

Comment: @martinclayton I think my application is sufficiently different that I asked a question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986120/bash-renaming-files

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash -f
files=`ls $1`
for file in $files; do
        if [ -d $file ];then
          java myProg $file
          # java your_program_name directory_i
        fi
done
```

Comment: i intended a backquote at `ls $1` but escaping it wont work although..:P

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in */.; do
  echo "$i" aka "${i%/.}"
  : your_command
done
```