# Deleting files after adding to tar archive

Tags: bash, unix, compression, tar

Can GNU tar add many files to an archive, deleting each one as it is added?

This is useful when there is not enough disk space to hold both the entire tar archive and the original files - and therefore it is not possible to simply manually delete the files after creating an archive in the usual way.

Comment: Are ALL of the files which exist in the directory must be compressed?

Comment: Doesn't `man tar` answer your question?

Comment: yes, I have a directory called images. I was doing

tar cvjf images.tar.bz2 images/

but I ran out of disk space.

Comment: One solution can be to do ftp for entire files to another machine --> archive it --> then move back "archived files" to the same machine

Comment: I'd rather not do that, as there are a lot of files, and I may need to do it again with even more

Comment: @lanzz No, as the bsd tar *doesn't* have the `--remove-files` option as shown in the gnu tar man page.

Comment: @bfcoder No, it would still answer the question. If you're on bsd, `man tar` would show you the man page for bsd tar, not for gnu tar.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

With GNU tar, use the [option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) `--remove-files`.

Comment: Are you sure that by using this flag will remove each file after adding it to the archive rather than deleting all the files in the end of the process?

Comment: @EugeneS: I checked the GNU tar source code and there is some (configurable) delay between archiving and removal, but tar will not wait for the entire tarball to be created.

Comment: How about bsdtar? Anyone?

Comment: Works great. Helps to make backups by pg_dump -Fd

Answer (score 6):

I had a task - archive files and then remove into OS installed "tar" without GNU-options.

#### Method:

Use "xargs"

Suppose, we are have a directory with files.

Need move all files, over the week into tar and remove it.

I do one archive (arc.tar) and added files to it. (You can create new archive every try)

#### Solution:

```
find ./ -mtime +7 | xargs -I % sh -c 'tar -rf arc.tar % && rm -f %'
```

Comment: 1. I would use `&&` instead of `;` between `tar` and `rm` commands, so only remove files if their addition to the archive was successful. 2. Consider using `-exec` option if your `find` has it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043896/711006

Answer (score 4):

For non GNU tar, you can use "-u" to proccess file per file in a loop

```
tar -cf archive.tar afile
for myfile in dir/*.ext
do
    tar -uf archive.tar $myfile && rm $myfile || echo "error tar -uf archive.tar $myfile"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: note the flag that's truly necessary here is `-r`, "append", although `-u`, "update", also includes it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can add files to bzip2 archives without first extracting. However here is one solution that just came to my mind (giving you the pseudoish algorithm):

```
1. For each [file] in [all small files]
    1.1 compress [file] into [file].bz2
    1.2 (optionally verify the process in some way)
    1.3 delete [file]
2. For each [bzfile] in [all bzip files from step 1]
    2.1 append to tar (tar rvf compressedfiles.tar [bzfile]
    2.2 (optionally verify the process in some way)
    2.3 delete [bzfile]
```

Now you should have a tar file containing all files individually bzip2:ed files. The question is how much overhead bzip2 adds to the individual files. This needs to be tested.