# Deleteing files after adding to tar

Tags: archive, freebsd, tar

Currently I'm working on my bash script which does backup mysql data, the only problem I got is the parameter of `tar` which was working on the `debian`, but its not working on `FreeBSD`.

Yes, I have read this:
[Deleting files after adding to tar archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781609/deleting-files-after-adding-to-tar-archive)

And the answer is the solution I was always using on `debian` - I mean the `--remove-files` parameter.

Executing the following command on FreeBSD:

`tar --remove-files -jcPf $DIR/$Y/$M/$D/mysql-$HOUR.tar.bz2 *.sql`

Throws the following error:

```
tar: Option --remove-files is not supported
```

I havent found anything similar to the `--remove-files` param. while reading the `man tar`, so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be tar option?  Most probably --remove-files is gnu extension (or whatever), so you'd probably be able to just install this 'extended' version of tar on FreeBSD and use it.

If you cannot/don't want to, I think this would do:

```
tar -jvcPf $DIR/$Y/$M/$D/mysql-$HOUR.tar.bz2 *.sql | xargs rm
```

BTW, I think the '-' can (and should) be omitted from the tar options...

Comment: `xargs rm` doesnt works, it leaves the files without removing them.

Comment: try adding -f option: ... | xargs rm -f