# execute a subprocess in a GNU parallel command

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I would like to do something like

```
find ./ -type f | parallel --gnu convert "{}" "$(basename "{}" pdf)jpg"
```

But it does not work (the files are renamed to `filename.pdfjpg`). I think the problem is that the subprocess is executed right away (even before calling `parallel`). I would like the subprocess to be executed for each file.

Thanks to [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands) I can do:

```
find *.pdf -exec sh -c 'convert "$1" "$(basename "$1" pdf)png"' _ {} \;
```

but I would like to use `GNU parallel`. The following does not work:

```
find ./ -type f | parallel --gnu sh -c 'convert "$1" "$(basename "$1" pdf)jpg"' _ {}
```

Of course, I can do this with two commands (e.g. using `rename`) but I would like to learn how to do it with one and with `GNU parallel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the files have the `.pdf` extension, you can use GNU parallel's extension stripping syntax:

```
find ./ -type f | parallel --gnu convert {} {.}.jpg
```

(No need to quote {}; parallel does it for you.)

Otherwise, you have to use `bash -c`:

```
find ./ -type f | parallel --gnu bash -c 'convert "$1" "${1/%.pdf}.jpg"' bash {}
```

(The second `bash` is there because `$1` is actually the second argument after the command string. Many people like to use `_`, since the value doesn't really matter.)