# *nix: Performing nested -exec with find command

Tags: php, linux, grep, find, exec

I'm trying do the following thing: Hunt down all 777 directories, and then within those directories, hunt down those php files which contain the string "mail(". My goal is to make this part of a cron-job which runs every night and finds all of the php files which contain mail functions that may have been inserted surreptitiously onto our server. So, I've written this command:

```
find -type d -perm 777 -exec find {} -name "*.php" \; -exec grep "mail(" {} \;
```

Which (is supposed to):

1: find the folders with 777 privileges

2: for each such folder, find all php files contained therein

3: for each such file, perform a grep to find the string "mail("

However, it doesn't appear to be working. What it is doing is giving me a list of php files in 777-privileged directories, but it's not performing the grep. I've looked at some SO postings like this:

[find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands)

Which lead me to believe that nesting of -exec is possible. Is there anything obvious I'm missing? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't nest `find -exec`, but you can nest `sh` which in turns calls `find -exec`. With GNU find, you also have to rewrite the `{}` in the inner find so that the outer find won't replace it:

```
find . -type d -perm 777 \
  -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -name "*.php" -exec grep "mail(" {""} \;' _ {} \;
```

This is the most direct answer to your question. There are multiple ways of simplifying it:

```
find . -type d -perm 777 \
  -exec find {} -name '*.php' -print0 \; | xargs -0 grep -H 'mail('
```

And an even simpler 90% version would just use `grep` to recurse:

```
find . -type d -perm 777 -exec grep -HR 'mail(' \; | grep '\.php'
```

Comment: Can you explain why the inner {} works only when expressed as {""}?

Comment: @UndergroundCoding The outer find `find` replaces the two character string `{}` wherever it sees it, but `{""}` is a four character string it doesn't recognize

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
find somewhere -type d -perm 777 -execdir grep mail *.php
```