# How to find and rename all files using -exec

Tags: linux, find, pipe, exec, rename

I want to rename all files which end on ".mp4" in such way that instead of white spaces to contain underscores.
Example:

```
Original file -> test 1.mp4
Renamed file -> test_1.mp4
```

I was trying with:

```
find . -iname "*.mp4"  -exec mv {} $(echo '{}' | tr " " "_") \;
```

But I got only:

```
mv: ‘./test 1.mp4’ and ‘./test 1.mp4’ are the same file
```

It seems that my pipe is not working.I would appreciate all ideas.

Comment: try `find . -iname "*.mp4"  -exec mv "{}" $(echo '{}' | tr " " "_") \;` Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively rename files using find and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed)

Answer (score -1):

I'd look into using the **rename** command, assuming your distribution provides it. In Debian: https://packages.debian.org/rename

If you don't need to search in subdirectories:

`rename 's/\ /_/' *.mp4`

If you do:

`find . -iname "*.mp4" -execdir rename 's/\ /_/' {} \;`

If multiple spaces must be replaced, the search/replace expression becomes `'s/\ /_/g'`

If you really want to keep your syntax/approach, see this very similar question: [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946)

Comment: As the search will be recursive the "find" way should be more appropriate, but it gives an error:
[code]$ find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec rename 's/\ /_/' {} \;
rename: not enough arguments[/code]

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce your error. I'm assuming that your distro (which one is it?) has a different command that answers to "rename". But in my tests, I found that my recursive answer will fail (with a different error) when encountering directories whose names contain spaces. I've therefore removed that part of the answer.

Comment: The distribution is CentOS 7. Indeed "rename" exists , but I have never managed to make it work.

Comment: I saw your answer, glad you found a solution that works for you. I've fixed and re-added my recursive solution - you might want to look into -execdir instead of -exec in yours too, in case your directory names contain spaces too. And remember, man is your friend :-)

Comment: As you've already found out, CentOS's rename is indeed different: http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/1/rename/

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the only way to do it so far is via "rename" command.

Here is the command that worked:

```
find /tmp/test/ -iname "*.mp4" -exec rename " " "_" "{}" \;
```

Comment: This only replaces the first space character and must be rerun multiple times to replace all .