# How to use bash's find arguments in if statements?

Tags: bash, if-statement, find

Just as the title says. I know how to use find's arguments in line with it, but not how to use them as if statements while evaluating a find return variable.  For example:

```
find . -type f
```

This obviously finds all the files, and how I'm looking to use it is:

```
ARRAY=$(find .)
for item in $ARRAY
do
if [[ -f $item ]] ; then
```

And that does the same thing, it only deals with the files from the find.  I obviously know how to do it with the `-type` argument, but not the others.  For example:

```
find . -size +512k
```

if I want size, doing `if [[ -size +512k $item ]]` doesn't seem to work as expected.  How do I use it?

Others I can't figure out how to use:

```
find . -executable
find . \( -name "*.html" -or -name "*.css" \)
find . -mtime +364
```

How would I use each of these in `if` statements if I'm looping over the results of a find?

Additionally, how would I grab the total size of a find result, after the fact, not during the find.   Say I have my `ARRAY=$(find .)` and what to do a `du -ch` against my `$ARRAY` variable.  How would I do that?

Sorry, I'm a bash noob and its syntax is proving difficult for me.

Comment: Is there a single question, or multiple questions? Or are you not sure what the question is?

Comment: mutiple questions.  It's wordy, I know.

Comment: `bash` and `find` are two completely separate commands. You can't use arguments for one with the other.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. The test(`[ ]`) or extended test(`[[  ]]`) are primitive enough so that they can't deal with everything that comes to your mind.

Comment: @user3066571 As a side note, `ARRAY=$(find .)` might not be doing what you think it does. Moreover, using full uppercase identifiers for user defined variables is a very bad idea as it may break built-in variables which are meant for the shell. `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

There's really no relationship between the `find` command (which is a standalone program, not actually part of Bash) and the `[[ ... ]]` syntax (which is built into Bash). So it should be no surprise that options supported by the `find` command need not have counterparts supported by the `[[ ... ]]` syntax.

For a complete list of what's supported by the `[[ ... ]]` syntax, see the *Bash Reference Manual*, [§3.2.4.2 "Conditional Constructs"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) and [§6.4 "Bash Conditional Expressions"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

To test if `"$foo"` is an executable file:

```
if [[ -x "$foo" ]] ; then
```

To test if something ends in `.html` or `.css`:

```
if [[ "$foo" == *.html ]] || [[ "$foo" == *.css ]] ; then
```

The others are not so easy, and will require recourse to external programs such as `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick

```
find . -size +10k -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; if [ $(du -k "$f" | cut -f 1) -gt 100000 ]; then echo "$f" ;fi' _ {} ';'
```

With the help of this answer: [find -exec with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119946/find-exec-with-multiple-commands)