# Use of underscore _ in bash find command

Tags: bash, shell, sh

What is the use of the **underscore** `_` in the `find` command below which is a command to create a file in **all directories**?

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "nameofyourwebsite" > "$1"' _ {}/downloaded.txt \;
```

**And if**  `{}` is a placeholder that is holding the directory names then **why** is the `echo` command **redirecting** to `$1`?

**or** `$1` is first argument which is `{}/downloaded.txt` ?

Please explain in the simplest way how this command is working.

Comment: Btw: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: This all has to do with how `sh -c` works -- see my answer to [this Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384219/difference-in-executing-a-command-line-in-a-different-ways)

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5121324/3266847).

Comment: Try `sh -c 'echo "$0"' _`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson i can't comment there due to low rep. one question you mentioned that But what's that ```installer-thingie``` argument? That's the name the mini-script is run under, so it'll show up as ```$0``` inside the mini-script. Basically, it functions as a placeholder, and you could put pretty much anything there.
what if i change this to ```installer-thingie``` any random name or my name is there any effect on command output or i can type anything here

Comment: @Sadam You can change it to any random name; it won't have any effect unless the mini-script refers to `$0`.