# Bash -- Renaming Files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I would like to write a script to rename a massive number of files by a few different rules.  I need to remove a specific string from some, then rename others by regex (some of which will be the ones that I previously removed the string from), then rename others based on the numbers in their filenames.

In general, let's say I have multiple directories (hundreds) that all look generally like this:

```
1234-pic_STUFF&TOREMOVE_2000.tiff
1234-pic_STUFF&TOREMOVE_4000.tiff
1234-MORESTUFFTOREMOVE-012.jpg
1234-MORESTUFFTOREMOVE-037.jpg
1234-STUFF&TOREMOVE.pptx.pdf        (don't ask about this one)
1234-ET.jpg
1234-DF.jpg
```

To one that looks like:

```
1234_smallNum.tiff
1234_bigNum.tiff
1234_smallNum.jpg
1234_bigNum.jpg
1234_CaseReport.pdf
1234_ET.jpg
1234_DF.jpg
```

I already have shell scripts that use a perl script to rename by regex (I got it off SO, but I can't find it again to reference it).  They are like `remove_stuff_to_remove.sh` and `rename_case_reports.sh`, and I can cd to each directory and do them individually by calling them with no input.

However, I don't know how to convert the filenames based on the numbers (2000 and 012 to smallNum; 4000 and 037 to bigNum; note these numbers vary greatly, so I can't go by a range or regex; I have to compare the numbers to each other.)

And I don't know how to automate the whole process, so that I can call one script from the root directory of all these directories and it will do all of these things for me.  I understand regexes pretty well, but I am not doing so well with the `find` command, or with shell scripting in general.

Also, I say Bash, but really, if this could be better done in Java, C, Python, Ruby, or Lisp, I know those languages much better, and I just want a solution to this before I get these files dumped on me (in the next month or so)...

Comment: As an aside comment, Perl or Bash seems to be the most relevant choices to accomplish this kind of task.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand. Are you sure that you can't have more than two files, in a directory, with the same name, same extension but a different number?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  It's medical data, and there are at most 2 "scans" for each (but there might only be one, in which case it's assumed to be small).

Comment: Can you perhaps provide some *real* example data?  Or are you suggesting that `1234_bigNum.tiff` is an actual literal filename that you might end up with?

Comment: I would like an algorithmic solution, that doesn't rely on my exact data.  I've spent a lot of time looking at similar questions, and the answers are basically useless unless you've got the exact same problem as the OP.  I would like to actually learn about the tools available to do this kind of thing, so that I can generalize the answer to other applications.  Like I said, I understand regexes, and I even have regexes that recognize my exact data, I just can't figure out how to apply them to this renaming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really - don't torture yourself with bash, just use your favorite scripting language.  The following will give you some idea how to approach this in Ruby.  Written hastily, so please don't laugh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'find'

def move(path, old_name, new_suffix)
    number = old_name.sub(/^(\d+).*/,'\1')
    File.rename(path+'/'+old_name, path+'/'+number+'_'+new_suffix)
end

where_to_look = ARGV[0] || '.'
Find.find(where_to_look) do |dir|
    path = where_to_look+'/'+dir
    next if !File.directory?(path)
    entries = Dir.entries(path).select{|x| File.file?(path+'/'+x) }
    next if entries.size != 7

    %w(tiff jpg).each do |ext|
        imgs = entries.select{|x| x =~ /\d+\.#{ext}$/ }
        next if imgs.size != 2
        imgs.sort{|a,b| ai = $1.to_i if a =~ /(\d+)\.#{ext}$/ ; bi = $1.to_i if b =~ /(\d+)\.#{ext}$/ ; ai <=> bi }
        move(path, imgs.first, 'smallNum.'+ext)
        move(path, imgs.last, 'bigNum.'+ext)
    end
    report = entries.detect{|x| x =~ /\.pptx\.pdf$/ }
    move(path, report, 'CaseReport.pdf') if !report.nil?
    %w(ET DF).each do |code|
        file = entries.detect{|x| x =~ /^\d+-#{code}\.jpg$/ }
        move(path, file, code+'.jpg') if !file.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: wow just goes to show how tired I've been lately... I completely forgot about all the nice file methods in Ruby...  I got stuck on the idea of using bash and ran into a wall.  I blame my professors who won't let me use anything but C this semester. :P

Answer (score 1):

Bash's string replacement:

```
$ match="foo"
$ repl="bar"
$ value="___foo___"
$ echo "${value/$match/$repl}"
___bar___
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

You can apply this pattern to each of your transformations.

```
$ for file in $(find . -name "*-pic_STUFF\&TOREMOVE_2000.tiff"); do
    mv "$file" "${file/-pic_STUFF\&TOREMOVE_2000.tiff/_smallNum.tiff}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for the example of Bash string replacement; I've never seen anyone do this before (+1 for that).  But this doesn't fix the problem of comparing the 2 numbers (2000 and 4000 are just examples, it could just as easily be 3750 and 4100).